# python selenium | ask for input, output it to a website?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

it's my first time posting here so sorry if i make any mistakes.. anyhow:

i have this script that goes on my school's website and inputs my login info, and checkmarks something that basically means that im feeling good (and that i don't have COVID).

im trying to get this to my friends at school but i don't want to give them the code, as im afraid they would touch it and mess something up... so i want to make something simple like this:
[simple GUI i made using tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QS76.png)

problem is, i don't know how to store the input im getting from there into a variable to then call later on in the script to print it out on the school website.. here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time

import tkinter as tk

def show_entry_fields():
    print("Username: %s\nPassword: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master,
         text="Username").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master,
         text="Password").grid(row=1)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

username = e1.get()
password = e2.get()

tk.Button(master, 
          text='Go', 
          command=master.quit).grid(row=3, 
                                    column=0, 
                                    sticky=tk.W, 
                                    pady=4)


tk.mainloop()


#opens the browser & website
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\Documents\Mashov\Haxarat Briut\chromedriver.exe")
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("blah blah blah")
time.sleep(2)

#types the school name
school = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-3']")
school.send_keys("blah blah bla")
school.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)



#types username
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mat-input-0']")
username.send_keys(username)
username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)



#types password
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-4"]')
password.send_keys(password)
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
```

if anyone has any pointers, or any help at all i would really appreciate it!
have a nice holiday!

EDIT: and if there is a simple way of storing this data so they don't have to type it in each time they open the program.. that would also be very helpful
(basically just the first time they open the program it'll ask for login details and then the next time you open it it'll just go automatically to the website without even asking for your login details)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make a directory called "autologin config" or something, in an easy to find place.  Have your script check for the existence of a text file called "autologin.txt" or something similar.  If it doesn't exist create it, ask for the username and write it to the file.  Then write a newline (\n), and ask for the password.  Append it to the second line of the file.  If the file does exist, or after making it, automatically go to the school's website and pull the login credentials from "C:\Users\User\Desktop\autologin config\ autologin.txt" or whatever your file is called, and use them to sign in.

Comment: I hope this helps address your needs well enough.  I would actually write out an example script but I'm at work at the moment.

Comment: consider encryption here.... using your machine's serial# as the key.  (Since you are storing login info.)

Comment: Most definitely @pcalkins.

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise to use encryption. That being said, I took the liberty to make a template that would serve your purpose using a self-generated CSV file to store the user information.

I suggest picking apart what I wrote below and self suiting it to fit your needs.

```
import tkinter as tk
import csv 
import os 

class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root 
        self.username = "" 
        self.password = ""

        # Some random consant file name
        self.USER_PROFILE = 'user-profile.csv' 

        # Entries 
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)

        # Buttons
        self.go_button = tk.Button(self.root, command=self.goPressed, text='Go')
     
    def setUI(self):
        # Labels
        tk.Label(self.root, text='Username').grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(self.root, text='Password').grid(row=1, column=0)

        # Entries
        self.username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        #Buttons
        self.go_button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)

    def show(self):
        self.setUI()

    def goPressed(self):
        self.updateUserProfile()
        self.root.quit()

    def updateUserProfile(self):
        self.username = self.username_entry.get()
        self.password = self.password_entry.get()
        # Create the user profile file if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.isfile(self.USER_PROFILE):
            # Make sure user filled the entries
            if self.username and self.password:
                with open(self.USER_PROFILE, 'w', newline='') as up:
                    writer = csv.writer(up)
                    # Write the row for the user name into the file 
                    writer.writerow(['username', self.username])
                    # and password...
                    writer.writerow(['password', self.password])

        # Otherwise, a profile already exists, I would modify this to
        # change the username and password if say, a "change username or password"
        # checkbox is set. 
        else:
            # Read the user profile
            with open(self.USER_PROFILE, 'r') as up:
                reader = csv.reader(up)
                # Read user info into selenium.
                # Right here I just have it write into the entry, but
                # it should be easy for you to change that to a selenium entry.
                for line in reader:
                    if line[0] == 'username':
                        self.username = line[1]
                        self.username_entry.insert(0, self.username)
                    elif line[0] == 'password':
                        self.password = line[1]
                        self.password_entry.insert(0, self.password)
    
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    window = Window(root)
    window.show()
    root.mainloop()

    #opens the browser & website
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\Documents\Mashov\Haxarat 
    Briut\chromedriver.exe")
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get("blah blah blah")
    time.sleep(2)

    #types the school name
    school = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-3']")
    school.send_keys("blah blah bla")
    school.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)

    #types username
    username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mat-input-0']")
    username.send_keys(window.username)
    username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)

    #types password
    password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-4"]')
    password.send_keys(window.password)
    password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Comment: i will try to do it, i'll reply if i get it working.. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is run ready code, so feel free to copy and paste to see how it works. If this helps you, please set this as the accepted answer.

Comment: it works perfectly, only problem im having is printing out the username and password in the selenium script, any idea how? i tried using self.username or even just username but it wouldn't work..

Comment: Place an edit in your question with your code attempt, and I'll guide you through it.

Comment: Also, if you're using Selenium outside of the "Window" class, you would have to access the user information through the class object. Assuming you have a member named "self.username" once you have user entry in the self.username you would write, " username.send_keys(window.username) ".

Comment: I've modified my answer to solve your issue, let me know if that works for you.